# Custom format for java.time.LocalDate is throwing DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, java-time

I would like to parse a date format **YYYY-MM-DD** into the following **MMM dd, yyyy**.
This is my part of code which is causing DateTimeParseException - >

`DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy"); LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2002-10-01",dateTimeFormatter1);`

The exception message when I try to parse the date with the given format is:
`Method threw 'java.time.format.DateTimeParseException' exception. Text '2002-10-01' could not be parsed at index 0.`

Comment: Your formatter is for the output pattern. You need 2 formatters. One to parse, and one to output. You can't just use 1 formatter and expect it to read your mind about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `2002-10-01` is in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, so trying to parse (i.e. convert it to a LocalDate object) it with format `MMM dd, yyyy` isn't going to work.

You need two formats to do this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy");

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2002-10-01",dateTimeFormatter1);
String newRepresentation = dateTimeFormatter2.format(localDate);

System.out.println(newRepresentation);
```

Comment: I had no problems by getting an string object for the format MMM dd, yyyy. The problem is I would need to have it as an LocalDate object in MMM dd, yyyy format . So for the following example I would need to have Oct 01, 2002 of LocalDate object.

Kind regards

Comment: @JasminJaskoMerušić That sounds like you expect the `LocalDate` object to have knowledge of how it should be formatted. It does not (and should not). The whole point of `DateTimeFormatter` is to convert date/time objects to strings, and vice versa. It's the `DateTimeFormatter` that knows how to parse and format, not the date/time objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your exception was caused by your specified parsing format `"MMM dd, yyyy"` not matching the input `2002-10-01`.

[You commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639152/custom-format-for-java-time-localdate-is-throwing-datetimeparseexception/67640003#comment119555869_67639255):

> I would need to have it as an LocalDate object in MMM dd, yyyy format

A `LocalDate` does not have a “format”. Text has a format, but `LocalDate` is not text.

The `LocalDate` class can parse an incoming string to produce a `LocalDate` object. And a `LocalDate` object can generate a string that represents its value. But a `LocalDate` object itself is neither of those strings. `LocalDate` has its own internal representation of a date, the details of which do not concern us.

You said:

> I would like to parse a date format YYYY-MM-DD

That format complies with the ISO 8601 standard. The *java.time* classes use those standard formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2002-10-01" ) ;
```

You said

> … into the following MMM dd, yyyy.

Generally better to let *java.time* automatically localize rather than you hard-code a specific format.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```